# How to get both IPv4 and IPv6 dynamic address

Tags: linux, dhcp, ip-address, ipv6

Running `dhclient` gets me an IPv4 address.

Running `dhclient -6` gets me an IPv6 address.

And the man page says you can't combine v4 and v6. So how to get both v4 and v6 addresses at the same time?

Comment: Doesn't your operating system distribution have network startup scripts to handle this for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can issue both commands and have them run concurrently in one line like:

`(dhclient &); (dhclient -6 &)`

You could then add it to a BASH script or alike, named how you'd like. :)

More info on combining commands in Linux:

- http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/manual2/runningcommands.html
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=531589
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077241/execute-combine-multiple-linux-commands-in-one-line

Answer (score 1):

If they can't be combined, you'll have to make two separate calls of `dhclient` and if you want this to run with one command, you could wrap it in a little shell-script. You can find [infos on Bash-scripting here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html).